# Javascript validation of user input

Tags: javascript, validation

Trying to make a code where the user must input a string from a certain list to proceed. I am using a constant to list the valid strings however I need to be able to have two values be seen as equal.

```
const VALID_STATE = ('queensland%qld%new south wales%nsw%victoria%vic%northern territory%nt%western australia%wa%south australia%sa%tasmania%tas%australian capital territory%act');
```

How can I change this so that I can make QUEENSLAND and QLD be seen as the same value and therefore one is not valid if the other has already been entered. Below is the code I'm using to validate the user input.

```
state = prompt('Input a state name:');
    while(VALID_STATE.indexOf(state.toLowerCase())<0){
        alert('The input state was not valid.');
        state = prompt('Re-enter the state name:');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue with you current code ?

Comment: A user can enter 'queensland' (and then go through with the rest of the code) then when it loops they can enter 'qld' and they are stored as two different values. I need a way to either make them equal to each other or be seen as the same value.

Comment: Doesnt it work like this already ?

Comment: No as they can enter 'queensland' and then 'qld' currently. I want to make that not happen.

Comment: May be you can use two different collections of valid inputs, one for full names and other for short ones. And somehow maintain a 'previous' value and compare current with that.

Answer (score 1):

How about if someone enters `"nd%ql"`..? This is not the right way to do this job. Keep them in a Map object and map both `"queensland"` key and `"qld"` key to the same name of your choice.

```js
var stateMap = new Map([['queensland','qld'], ['qld','qld'], ['new south wales', 'nsw'], ['nsw', 'nsw'], ['victoria', 'vic'], ['vic', 'vic'], ['northern territory', 'nt'], ['nt', 'nt'], ['western australia', 'wa'], ['wa', 'wa'], ['south australia', 'sa'], ['sa', 'sa'], ['tasmania', 'tas'], ['tas', 'tas'], ['australian capital territory', 'act'], ['act', 'act']]);

var state = prompt('Enter a state.');
while (!stateMap.has(state.toLowerCase())){
  alert('The input state was not valid.');
  state = prompt('Enter a state.');
}
state = stateMap.get(state);
```